# Can't use Managed Service identity (MSI) for App Service deployment with hosted Microsoft agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager, azure-managed-identity

We have a release pipeline that is failing with following message:

> resource ID for resource type 'Microsoft.Web/Sites' and resource name
> 'appservicename'. Error: Could not fetch access token for Managed
> Service Principal. Please configure Managed Service Identity (MSI) for
> virtual machine 'https://aka.ms/azure-msi-docs'. Status code: 400,
> status message: Bad Request

We have 2 different service connections:

- Azure Resource Manager using service principal authentication
- Azure Resource Manager using managed identity authentication

The first one works like a charm. However, because the developer wanted to limit admin access on the Azure AD, he tried creating a managed identity authentication service connection which at first glance, since it allowed us to select the App Service, appeared to indicate it's working, until an actual deployment was triggered and it failed per the error message above.

After numerous searches online, I think [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/error-failed-to-get-resource-id-for-resource-type/352721#TPIN-N1183334) answer may be the clue to why this is failing with the managed identity authentication service connection yet succeeding with the service principal connection just fine.

***I just want to confirm, is this truly the case?*** that a hosted agent doesn't support MSI based authentication, which is what we are using… or has that changed?

We are indeed using Microsoft agent pool.

[image: MS pool]

It doesn't make sense for our app service to use a VM at this time. The use case just isn't applicable for the dashboards we have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is written in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops#create-an-azure-resource-manager-service-connection-to-a-vm-with-a-managed-service-identity):

> You are required to use a self-hosted agent on an Azure VM in order to use managed service identity

I assume that it was alway like that. Here we are talking abut MSI assigned to VM which serves as build agent. Not MSI which is identity of App Service. Why? Service Connection is an abstraction which makes easy authentication to your Azure Subscription. So it gives identity to VM and then when your perform some action against your Azure thanks to MSI Azure know that can perform that action. Another aption is authentication via Service Principal, but thi can be done from any VM (inlcuding MS Hosted) because it relies on Client Id and Client secret which is kept in service connections. And MSI have to be assigned to particular VM which cannot be done with MS Hosted agents.